# How to take the most frequent number added to the array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

my code is a math game with rand numbers and operations at the end i ask the user if they want to show the operation with the most wrong/right  answers i made each time the user answers right/wrong it will add the operation to a WrongOperationArray/RightOperationArray but how do i show the most frequent operation in each array

```
     string[] operators = new string[4]{ "+", "-", "*", "/" };
          
     
            }
            // LOOP THAT WILL SHOW THE QUESTIONS AND ADD THE RIGHT ANSWERS AND WRONG TO A LIST .
        
            string[] rightoperationlist = new string[numofquestions];
            string[] wrongoperationlist = new string[numofquestions];
            while (numofquestionsleft > 0 && m <=numofquestions+1)
            {
              
                  string op = operators[randomgen.Next(operators.Length)];
                 
                      switch (op)
                      {
                          case "+":
                              answer = num01 + num02;

                              break;

                          case "-":
                              answer = num01 - num02;

                              break;
                          case "*":
                              answer = num01 * num02;

                              break;
                          case "/":
                              answer = Math.Round((double)num01 / (double)num02, 2);

                              break;
                      }

                      sss = Convert.ToString(answer);
                      //THE QUESTION
                      question = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", num01, op, num02);


                      Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
                      Console.WriteLine("What is = " + question + " Or type QUIT to ignore ");

                      Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
                      // IF USER TYPE QUIT THAT WILL SKIP THE QUESTION AND ADD IT TO WRONG ANSWERS LIST
                      if (useranswer == quit)
                      {
                          numofquestionsleft--;
                          ;
                          continue;

                      }
                      if (useranswer == sss)
                      //IF USER ANSWER IS CORRECT THE NUMBER OF CORRECT ANSWERS WILL +1 && add the operation to the array
                      {
                          numofcorrect++;
                          rightoperationlist[m] = op;

                      }
                      else
                      //IF USER ANSWER IS WRONG THE NUMBER OF WRONG ANSWERS WILL +1 && add the operation to the array
                      {
                          numoffalse++;
                          wrongoperationlist[m] = op;

                      }


                      numofquestionsleft--;
                      //LOOP
                      m++;
                  }
                  
             while (1 < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"TO GET THE NUMBER OF THE RIGHT ANSWERS PRESS 1
TO GET THE NUMBER OF THE WRONG ANSWERS PRESS 2
TO GET THE OPERATION WITH THE MAX NUMBERS OF RIGHT ANSWERS PRESS 3
TO GET THE OPERATION WITH THE MAX NUMBERS OF FALSE ANSWERS PRESS 4
TO VIEW ALL THE QUESTIONS AND YOUR ANSWERS AND CORRECT ANSWERS TYPE 5
TO EXIT TYPE EXIT
");
                sb = Console.ReadLine();

                b = Int32.Parse(sb);
                switch (b)
                {

                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("You have = " + numofcorrect + " Right answers");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("You have = " + numoffalse + " Wrong answers");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                  
                        for (int l=0;  l< numofcorrect;l++ )
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("RIGHT ANSWER OPERATION = " + rightoperationlist[l]);
                        }            
                            break;
                    case 4:              
                            for (int k = 0; k < numoffalse; k++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("WRONG ANSWER OPERATIONS = "+ wrongoperationlist[k]);
                            }  
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("QUESTIONS               ANSWERS                RIGHTANSWERS");
                        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        for (int z = 0; z < numofquestions; z++)
                            
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(questionlist[z]+"                 "+useranswerlist[z]+"                   "+rightanswerslist[z]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            break;
                        
                    default:
                        break;

                }
                
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq, there is example:

```
var result = (from operation in rightoperationlist
         group operation by operation into og
         orderby og.Count() descending
         select og.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, you can select the operation and the count of the array first.

Then, you can select the max count of the list.

Finally, you can get the correct result.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] operators = new string[4] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
            int numofquestions = 6;
            int numofquestionsleft = 2;
            Random random = new Random();
            double answer = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter two numbers");
            double num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int m = 0 ;
            string[] rightoperationlist = new string[numofquestions];
            string[] wrongoperationlist = new string[numofquestions];
            int numofcorrect = 0;
            int numoffalse = 0;
            while (numofquestionsleft > 0 && m <= numofquestions-1 )
            {

                string op = operators[random.Next(operators.Length)];

                switch (op)
                {
                    case "+":
                        answer = num01 + num02;

                        break;

                    case "-":
                        answer = num01 - num02;

                        break;
                    case "*":
                        answer = num01 * num02;

                        break;
                    case "/":
                        answer = Math.Round((double)num01 / (double)num02, 2);

                        break;
                }

                string sss = Convert.ToString(answer);
                //THE QUESTION
                string question = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", num01, op, num02);


                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("What is = " + question + " Or type QUIT to ignore ");

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
                string useranswer = Console.ReadLine();
                // IF USER TYPE QUIT THAT WILL SKIP THE QUESTION AND ADD IT TO WRONG ANSWERS LIST

                if (useranswer == sss)
                //IF USER ANSWER IS CORRECT THE NUMBER OF CORRECT ANSWERS WILL +1 && add the operation to the array
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("correct answer!");
                    numofcorrect++;
                    rightoperationlist[m] = op;

                }
                else
                //IF USER ANSWER IS WRONG THE NUMBER OF WRONG ANSWERS WILL +1 && add the operation to the array
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Answer");
                    numoffalse++;
                    wrongoperationlist[m] = op;

                }

                //numofquestionsleft--;
                //LOOP
                m++;
            }
            var correctresult= rightoperationlist.ToList().GroupBy(x => x)
              .Where(g => g.Count() >=1)
              .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() })
              .ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("The most frequent operation and the count in the correct array");
            int max1 = correctresult.Max(r => r.Counter);
            foreach (var item in correctresult)
            {
                if(item.Element!=null&&item.Counter==max1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The most operation is {0} and the count is {1}", item.Element, item.Counter);
                } 
            }
            var wrongresult = wrongoperationlist.ToList().GroupBy(x => x)
              .Where(g => g.Count()>=1)
              .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() })
              .ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("The most frequent operation and the count in the wrong array");
            int max2 = wrongresult.Max(r => r.Counter);
            foreach (var item in wrongresult)
            {
                if(item.Element!=null&&item.Counter==max2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The most operation is {0} and the count is {1}", item.Element, item.Counter);
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("success");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Tested result:

[image]